# Milwaukee SUG Holiday Get Together - December 13, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Wednesday, December 13, 2017, 5:00 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, December 13, 2017, 22:00

**Location:** [Third Space Brewing](https://thirdspacebrewing.com/), [1505 W St. Paul Ave., Milwaukee, WI](https://goo.gl/maps/iJqv9Ce8ssE2)

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Milwaukee-Sitecore-Developers-Meetup/events/245527831/

**Organizers:**

- [Rick Bauer](https://twitter.com/sitecordial)
- [Derek Dysart](https://twitter.com/ddysart)
- [Paul Plakut](https://www.linkedin.com/in/paulplakut/)
- [Mark Servais](https://twitter.com/mservais)

### Agenda

- 5:00 - 9:00 PM: Food, refreshments, networking

### Presentations

No presentations - but a chance for everyone to casually get together and informally discuss Sitecore, marketing, and development over drinks and food.