# Sitecore St. Louis User Group, Jan 31, 2018

Tags: discussion

Join us for our first meetup this year.  We had a great year last year and we aim to do better this year.  So, if you're in the St. Louis area on Jan. 31st, come for a visit.  We'll be tackling these topics:

- Unicorn
- SXA
- Personalization

Date/Time (CST): Wed, Jan 31, 2018, 12:00 PM

Date/Time (UTC): Wed, Jan 31, 2018, 18:00

Location: Watlow Electric Manufacturing Company -- 12001 Lackland Road, St. Louis, MO

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/Saint-Louis-Sitecore-User-Group-Meetup/events/246870531/

**Organizers:**

Marco Tana

Brett Berchtold

**Agenda**

- 12:00 - 12:05 PM: Assembly
- 12:05 - 12:30 PM: Technical Considerations
  for Personalizations - Gilbert BLocker
- 12:30 - 12:55 PM: Getting
  Started with Unicorn - Benjamin Vidal
- 12:55 - 1:20: SXA - Technical
  Deep Dive Part 1 - Marco Tana
- 1:20 - 130 PM: Networking and Closing

Find out more on our meetup page: https://www.meetup.com/Saint-Louis-Sitecore-User-Group-Meetup/events/246870531/

Presentations are recorded and made [available on our YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUa1dMY9DE9YRbe60SdXMng).

Comment: Please add times in UTC, location details and contact details. See this example: https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/milwaukee-sug-holiday-get-together-december-13-2017

Comment: I'm still confused. Date/Time says 18 Jan, but headline says 31 Jan?

Comment: My bad...copy/paste.  Now updated.